# Multiple orderBy filter (one is fixed another is from controller)-Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

my js function:

```
    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
    $scope.sortKey = keyname;   
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; 
}
```

HTML:

```
      <th ng-click="sort('PaymentID')">
                    <a>Payment ID</a>
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PaymentID'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                </th>
                <th ng-click="sort('MemberID')"><a>Member ID</a>
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='MemberID'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                </th>
data-dir-paginate="item in data.payment|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
```

I have another field named 'Date'. I just want to filter 'Date' by decending(means recently added payment). I want to fixed filter by date by decending and another filter comes from sort function. 
How can i do this?
I tried this but no worked:

```
 data-dir-paginate="item in data.payment|orderBy:[sortKey,'-Date']:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
```

Comment: I think if you remove reverse filter it will work.

Comment: You are adding '-Date' which will order it in descending order.

Comment: It doesn't give my solution. I want date always on descending and another one comes from PaymentID or MemberID with ascending or descending based on click event. I edited my post with span and glyphicon  to show or hide an icon. @Akshay Kumar